# WPF Collapsed Control issue - ListBox not resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid in my main window with a horizontal grid splitter. In the upper part is an ordinary `ListBox` and in the lower part a User Control that contains a `ScrollViewer` and a `TextBox` in that.

The user can toggle the visibility of the lower control on/off through the menu. The lower control's `Visibility` is then set to `Collapse` (as is the grid splitter). This works OK if the controls aren't resized but if the user drags the grid splitter to resize the lower control and the toggles the lower control of then the `ListBox` is stuck with the last height and wont extends back to the bottom of the window (see screenshot).

All the components are set to `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` in the Xaml so I think the `ListBox` should stretch back to the bottom after the lower control is collapsed again. What do I have to keep in mind to get this working?

[image: screenshot]

Code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="2">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Add Game..." x:Name="menuItemAddGame" Uid="addGame" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Settings..." x:Name="menuItemSettings" Uid="settings" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" x:Name="menuItemExit" Uid="exit" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View">
                <MenuItem Header="_Games Details" x:Name="menuItemViewModeDetails" Uid="viewModeDetails" IsCheckable="True" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Games List" x:Name="menuItemViewModeList" Uid="viewModeList" IsCheckable="True" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Games Grid" x:Name="menuItemViewModeGrid" Uid="viewModeGrid" IsCheckable="True" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Log" x:Name="menuItemShowLog" Uid="showLog" IsCheckable="True" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_Website" x:Name="menuItemWebsite" Uid="website" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Check for Updates" x:Name="menuItemCheckUpdate" Uid="checkUpdate" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_About..." x:Name="menuItemAbout" Uid="about" Click="OnMainMenuItemClick" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <ToolBarPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="30">
            <ToolBar x:Name="toolBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30"/>
        </ToolBarPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock>ListBox Item #1</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock>ListBox Item #2</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock>ListBox Item #3</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>

            <GridSplitter Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="4" Background="#EEEEEE"/>
            <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitterV" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Height="4" Background="#EEEEEE" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

        <sirius:LogView x:Name="logView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" MinHeight="20"/>

        <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Padding="2">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock x:Name="statusBarTextBlock" Text="Ready." />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**LogView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sirius.LogView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="640">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In **MainWindow.xaml.cs** I have this method to toggle the LogView:

```
public void ToggleLogView()
{
    if (logView.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        gridSplitterV.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        logView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        logView.Enabled = true;
        menuItemShowLog.IsChecked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        logView.Enabled = false;
        gridSplitterV.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        logView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        menuItemShowLog.IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us some xaml? Its hard to imagine

Comment: @Alander I've added the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before. A simple solution, that works consistently, is to set the row span of the still-visible row content to 3 when the splitter and the other row are collapsed.

So give the content for that row a name:

```
<Grid 
    x:Name="ListBoxGrid"
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

...and set the rowspan in your code behind:

```
    public void ToggleLogView()
    {
        if (logView.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            gridSplitterV.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            logView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            logView.IsEnabled = true;
            menuItemShowLog.IsChecked = true;

            Grid.SetRowSpan(ListBoxGrid, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            logView.IsEnabled = false;
            gridSplitterV.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            logView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            menuItemShowLog.IsChecked = false;

            Grid.SetRowSpan(ListBoxGrid, 3);
        }
    }
```

I'll spare you the MVVM homily because this is view-only code, but everything you're doing in `ToggleLogView`, plus my addition, could be very straightforwardly be done in XAML.

I had another option that worked in my simplified test XAML, but not with OP's full layout: Name the `*` RowDefinition and set its Height to `GridLength(1, GridUnit.Star);` when hiding the logview row. I didn't investigate why that failed with OP's XAML.

---

### Update

Pure XAML version. The menu item will toggle its IsChecked state automatically because you set `IsCheckable="True"` on it, so the click handler on that menu item can be entirely omitted. `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` is in `System.Windows.Controls`. No need to write your own converter. You could write a converter for the row span, if you wanted, and avoid the verbose Style I used.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ...snip... -->

            <MenuItem Header="_Log" x:Name="menuItemShowLog" Uid="showLog" IsCheckable="True" />

<!-- ...snip... -->

    <Grid 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        x:Name="ListBoxGrid"
        >
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=menuItemShowLog}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="3" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

         <!-- ...snip... -->

    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter 
        Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=menuItemShowLog, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
        ...
        />

    <sirius:LogView 
        Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=menuItemShowLog, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
        ...
        />
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Plunkett! The `Grid.SetRowSpan(ListBoxGrid, 3)` workaround does work for me. The `PermanentRow.Height ` does not.

Comment: @BadmintonCat Interesting. I didn't test these with your full layout; I'll have to copy your XAML and kick that around.

Comment: @BadmintonCat With your XAML, I'm seeing what you are. Got rid of that suggestion.

Comment: No worries! Not yet familiar with the MVVM paradigm but I want to learn about it and WPF development in general.